# Custom loss function for sports betting

Tags: keras, loss-function, loss

I'm trying to make a model that predicts the most profitable tennis matches to bet on. For that reason I included betting odds into yTrue variable so it may look like this:

`yTrue = np.array([[0,1,1.38,3.05],[1,0,1.05,7.85],[1,0,1.04,10.24],[1,0,1.22,3.71],[1,0,1.06,6.69],[1,0,1.48,2.46],[0,1,1.61,2.22]])`

yTrue[0] and yTrue[1]: favorite/underdog won/lost

yTrue[2] and yTrue[3]: favorite/underdog's odds

Let's say the bet is 1000 units so in our dataset: the first and last game have been won by the underdog, the other games were won by the favorite. If we made a bet of 1000 units on all the 7 matches and all of them were good, we would make a profit of 4120.0 units, so this is the maximum achievable profit. In case the predictions were like this: `yPred = np.array([[0,1], [0,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,0]])` 4 out of 7 predictions were correct so in total it would make a loss of -210.0 units.

In normal Python the loss function could look like this:

```
import numpy as np
yTrue = np.array([[0,1,1.38,3.05],[1,0,1.05,10.24],[1,0,1.04,7.85],[1,0,1.22,3.71],[1,0,1.06,6.69],[1,0,1.48,2.46],[0,1,1.61,2.22]])
yPred = np.array([[0,1], [0,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,0]])

def myLoss(yTrue, yPred):
        maxPotentialProfit = 0
        realProfit = 0
        betUnits = 1000
        for a in range(0,len(yTrue)):
                bet = yTrue[a]
                pred = yPred[a]
                favOdds = bet[2]-1
                dogOdds = bet[3]-1
                if bet[0] == 1:
                        maxPotentialProfit += favOdds*betUnits
                else:
                        maxPotentialProfit += dogOdds*betUnits

                if bet[0] == 1 and pred[0] == 1:
                        realProfit += favOdds*betUnits
                elif bet[1] == 1 and pred[1] == 1:
                        realProfit += dogOdds*betUnits
                else:
                        realProfit -=betUnits

        return maxPotentialProfit - realProfit
```

But now the real deal: how can I make it differentiable so it works with keras? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A model's prediction will never be on either extremes 0 or 1. It will be something in between; the closer the prediction is to the extreme means the more confident the model is.
2. It's wasteful to store both favorite/underdog won/lost, because won + loss = 1, you just need to store one variable and deduce the other.

So your data should look like this:

```
# 1 = favorite wins, 0 = underdog wins / favorite odd / underdog odd
yTrue = np.array([[0, 1.38, 3.05], [1, 1.05, 10.24],[1, 1.04, 7.85]])

# the predicted probability that favorite wins
yPred = np.array([0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
```

3. Unless you want `betUnits` to be part of the model's prediction, there's no need to get it involved in the loss function, because it would not affect the training.
4. The native Keras way to calculate `maxPotentialProfit` is

```
import keras.backend as K

# split yTrue into 3 columns for easy handling
result = yTrue[:, 0]
favOdds = yTrue[:, 1]
dogOdds = yTrue[:, 2]

# logic: check each element in result, 
# if 1, add the corresponding element in favOdds,
# else, add the corresponding element in dogOdds.
maxPotentialProfit = K.sum(K.switch(result==1, favOdds, dogOdds))
```

4. Since the prediction will never be either 0 or 1, a conditional like `if bet[0] == 1 and pred[0] == 1` won't work. Instead let's interpret an output of, say 0.7, as the model betting 0.7 units on the favorite and 0.3 units on the underdog.

```
# split the prediction
favPred = yPred
dogPred = 1 - yPred

# logic: check each element in result,
# if 1, add the corresponding element of favOdds*favPred,
# else, add the corresponding element of dogOdds*dogPred
realProfit = K.sum(K.switch(result==1, favOdds*favPred, dogOdds*dogPred))

# initial cost of betting: 1 for each bet
realProfit -= yPred.shape[0] # this is keras' equivalent of len()
# However, since this value is independent of the values yPred,
# it will have no effects on the training whatsoever, so we can remove it.

return maxPotentialProfit - realProfit
```

5. You may notice that the calculation for `maxPotentialProfit` and `realProfit` are very similar. So instead of calculating them individually, we can do combine them in one line.

Here's the full code:

```
import keras.backend as K

def myLoss(yTrue, yPred):
    result = yTrue[:, 0]
    favOdds = yTrue[:, 1]
    dogOdds = yTrue[:, 2]
    favPred = yPred
    dogPred = 1 - yPred
    return K.sum(K.switch(result==1, favOdds*(1-favPred), dogOdds*(1-dogPred)))
```

6. That's all, just a note: you can't call `myLoss` on some numpy arrays to test, because it expects Keras tensors as inputs. You need to build a Keras model and use `myLoss` as the loss function to see it working. But that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Great post, it made me finally understand it. Thank you so much!!